# Adding a custom error to a table after a invalid search has been run when there is already text in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

When a search is ran if there are no results a "No results found" line is added to the table.  When a invalid search is ran such as a user searching for a fake country.  I need to access the label database and enter the invalid country error instead of the "No results found".

```
if(SearchResults.empty){
   searchError.add(ss.getLabel("UASJSNSER", request));
   SearchResults.append(searchError);
}
```

This doesn't override the "No results found" that happens when there are no results.
The SearchResults is the table and the searchError the variable that holds the error when an search error happens.

***UPDATE***

SearchResults is the table that is filled with the data after the search runs.

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class=" sorting_1">0001UK</td>
<td class="">
<td class="">Pl,anPlus Inc</td>
<td class="">PlanPlus PlanIt</td>
<td class="">Permanent Access</td>
<td class=""></td>
<td class="">
<a href="loadAdvisor.do?planner=0001UK">Edit</a>
| 
<a href="javascript:popUp('deleteadvisor.jsp?action=&planner=0001UK');">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr> //this Is when a search happens that has results 

<tr class="odd">
<td class="dataTables_empty" valign="top" colspan="7">No records found</td>
</tr>
</tbody> //Instead of it saying No records found I need it to say the error I call from the database.
```

Comment: what is `SearchResults` ?

Comment: Can you show the generated html of the table?

Comment: We'd prefer that you don't keep asking the same question over and over. If you're not getting any answers then try to improve the question or earn some rep to post a bounty. Thanks.